# URL button on esp8266 webserver

Tags: html, arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm quite new to messing up with esp's, i've managed - USING ARDUINO IDE- to create a local page with buttons on it, one directs me to my local server and the other is the subject of my question, I need it to redirect me to a URI that is constantly changing, the URI is acquired from an arduino through serial connection any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

this is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSWORD";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

//Check if header is present and correct
bool is_authentified(){
  Serial.println("Enter is_authentified");
  if (server.hasHeader("Cookie")){
    Serial.print("Found cookie: ");
    String cookie = server.header("Cookie");
    Serial.println(cookie);
    if (cookie.indexOf("ESPSESSIONID=1") != -1) {
      Serial.println("Authentification Successful");
      return true;
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Authentification Failed");
  return false;
}

//login page, also called for disconnect
void handleLogin(){
  String msg;
  if (server.hasHeader("Cookie")){
    Serial.print("Found cookie: ");
    String cookie = server.header("Cookie");
    Serial.println(cookie);
  }
  if (server.hasArg("DISCONNECT")){
    Serial.println("Disconnection");
    server.sendHeader("Location","/login");
    server.sendHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    server.sendHeader("Set-Cookie","ESPSESSIONID=0");
    server.send(301);
    return;
  }
  if (server.hasArg("USERNAME") && server.hasArg("PASSWORD")){
    if (server.arg("USERNAME") == "98710" &&  server.arg("PASSWORD") ==     "hussein" ){
      server.sendHeader("Location","/");
      server.sendHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
      server.sendHeader("Set-Cookie","ESPSESSIONID=1");
      server.send(301);
      Serial.println("Log in Successful");
      return;
    }
  msg = "invalid username/password please try again";
  Serial.println("Log in Failed");
  }
  String content = "<center><div id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_TopHead\"><div     id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_ctl03_dvBody\" class=\"\"><div     id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_containerid\"><a     href=\"http://www.ungift.org/images/knowledgehub/logos/usaid-logo.jpeg\"><img     border=\"0\" alt=\"main page\"     src=\"http://www.ungift.org/images/knowledgehub/logos/usaid-logo.jpeg\"     width=\"930\" height=\"110\"></a></div></div></div></center>";
  content += "<center></center> ";
  content += "<center></center>";
  content += "<center><html><body><form action='/login' method='POST'>please     enter your info to be able to login<br></center>";
  content += "<center>Username:<input type='text' name='USERNAME'     placeholder='Username'><br></center>";
  content += "<center>Password:<input type='password' name='PASSWORD'     placeholder='Password'><br></center>";
  content += "<center><input type='submit' name='SUBMIT' value='sign in'>    </form>" + msg + "<br></center>";
  content += "<center>for more info<a href='/inline'>press here</a></body>    </html></center>";
  server.send(200, "text/html", content);
}

//root page can be accessed only if authentification is ok
void handleRoot(){
  Serial.println("Enter handleRoot");
  String header;
  if (!is_authentified()){
    server.sendHeader("Location","/login");
    server.sendHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    server.send(301);
    return;
  }
  String content = "<center><div id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_TopHead\"><div     id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_ctl03_dvBody\" class=\"\"><div     id=\"ucPageViewer_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_containerid\"><a     href=\"http://www.ungift.org\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"main page\"     src=\"http://www.ungift.org/images/knowledgehub/logos/usaid-logo.jpeg\"     width=\"930\" height=\"110\"></a></div></div></div></center>";
  if (server.hasHeader("User-Agent")){
  }
    content += "<center><img crossorigin=\"anonymous\"     src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ar/b/bf/Yarmouk_University_Logo.png    \"width=\"168\" height=\"250\"</center>";
    content += "<h1><center>hi there</center></h1>";
    content += "<center><p><a href=\"socket2On\"><button>go to link from     serial </button></a></p></center>";
    content += "<center><p>browse server   <a     href=\"192.168.1.240/main.html"><button>ON</button></a></p></center>";
    content += "please sign out before leaving <a href=\"/login?    DISCONNECT=YES\">sign out</a></body></html>";  

  server.send(200, "text/html", content);
}

//no need authentification
void handleNotFound(){
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/login", handleLogin);
  server.on("/inline", [](){
    String MGS = "<h1><center>please enter valid username and     password</center></h1>";
    MGS += "to go back to login page please press `enter code here`<a     href=\"/login?DISCONNECT=YES\">here</a></body></html>"; 
    server.send(200, "text/html", MGS );
  });
   server.on("/search", [](){
    String T = "";
     T = Serial.readString();
     Serial.print(T);
    server.send(200, "text/html", T );
  });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  //here the list of headers to be recorded
  const char * headerkeys[] = {"User-Agent","Cookie"} ;
  size_t headerkeyssize = sizeof(headerkeys)/sizeof(char*);
  //ask server to track these headers
  server.collectHeaders(headerkeys, headerkeyssize );
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
      }
```

Comment: What's wrong with printing a different value each time?

Comment: well, the character received from serial is  a replication of a URL written on an NFC tag, the button is supposed to direct me to that link, there is no problem with printing different values, the issue is reading them and redirection to them as the button is pressed

Comment: So when you click the button, you want the esp8266 to read the new URL from the serial port, send a new link to the browser, and then have the browser redirect to it?

Comment: yeah, thats exactly whatI need